# Bazel gives compilation error when converting matrix types

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, bazel, eigen3

I am using bazel to build some code. The code gives compilation error while doing dome matrix assignments.

```cpp
typedef Eigen::Matrix<double,44,44> stateMat_t;
typedef Eigen::Matrix<double,44,44> stateTens_t[44];   //44 x 44 x 44


// bunch of other code...

typedef std::vector<stateMat_t> stateTensTab_t;

// bunch of other code...

stateTensTab_t fxxList;
stateTens_t fxx;

// bunch of other code

fxxList[j][k] = fxx[j];

//bunch of other code
```

I expect the code to compile successfully, but it gives the following error:

```
error: cannot convert 'Eigen::Matrix<double, 44, 44>' to 'Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 44, 44>, 1>::Scalar {aka double}' in assignment
                     fxxList[j][k] = fxx[j];
```

Comment: Btw: You should always provide a [mre] -- even though in this case the error in your code was easy to spot anyway. And your problem is not bazel related at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to assign a `Matrix<double,44,44>` to a `double&`, since that is what `Matrix::operator[]` returns (the operator where you pass `k`). Calling that operator alone should also fail, since `stateMat_t` is not a vector at compile time.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Any suggestions to make it work would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Remove the `[k]`.